# How to derive variance from a regression model with only μ as the estimator (i.e. no coefficients)?

Tags: regression, variance, generalized-least-squares

I am having trouble deriving the variance of this regression model given below:[image]

So far, I have managed to derive the OLS estimate but I just cannot wrap my head around how the variance is derived here:[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

In the problem specified, $\hat{\mu}$ is defined as the sum of the $n$ reponse values $y_{i}$ divided by $n$. We can think of $\hat{\mu}$ as thus being a composite of the $y_{i}$ values.

The variance of a sum of several components is the sum of all of the elements of the variance-covariance matrix among the components (see the section on linear composites [here](http://psych.colorado.edu/%7Ecarey/Courses/PSYC7291/handouts/transformations.pdf)).

$V(y_{1} + y_{2} + y_{3} + ... + y_{n}) = \sum\begin{bmatrix}
σ^2_{1} & σ_{12} & σ_{13} & ... & σ_{1n}\\
σ_{21} & σ^2_{2} & σ_{23} & ... & σ_{2n}\\
σ_{31} & σ_{32} & σ^2_{3} & ... & σ_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
σ_{n1} & σ_{n2} & σ_{n3} & ... & σ^2_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$

This matrix is symmetric, so this sum can also be written as the sum of the diagonal elements (the variances of each component) plus 2 times each of the lower triangle elements (the covariance between each unique pair of components).

$V(y_{1} + y_{2} + y_{3} + ... + y_{n}) = \sum(σ^2_{1} + σ^2_{2} + ... + 2σ_{12} + 2σ_{13} + ...)$

When you divide variable by a constant, such as $n$, the variance of the result is equal to the original variance divided by the constant squared, hence

$V(\hat{\mu}) = V([y_{1} + y_{2} + y_{3} + ... + y_{n}]/n]) = V(y_{1} + y_{2} + y_{3} + ... + y_{n}) / n^2$

Subsituting everything together yields the formula from your question:

$V(\hat{\mu}) = \frac{1}{n^2} { \sum(σ^2_{1} + σ^2_{2} + ... + 2σ_{12} + 2σ_{13} + ...) }$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, this is a god-sent! But just to check, would the answer be (σ^2)/n as opposed to what was [given](https://imgur.com/a/fYXSlnY) by my lecturer?

Comment: No, as above: "When you divide variable by a constant, such as n, the variance of the result is equal to the original variance divided by the **constant squared**, hence…"